# Font Issues in React-Native UI Kitten Demo

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I've been stuck with this problem for a long time, and after many hours of googling i've decided to post this question.

Error is below:

```
console.error: "fontFamily "ionicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync."

__expoConsoleLog
    RemoteConsole.js:80:37
error
    YellowBox.js:59:8
error
    muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24
processFontFamily
    Font.js:35:16
diffProperties
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3545:38
addNestedProperty
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3419:6
diffProperties
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3556:8
createInstance
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4003:29
completeWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14437:12
completeUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17094:10
performUnitOfWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17304:30
workLoop
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17316:41
renderRoot
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17417:15
performWorkOnRoot
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18423:17
performWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18324:24
performSyncWork
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18285:14
batchedUpdates$1
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18531:21
batchedUpdates
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2611:31
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2706:17
receiveTouches
    ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2782:28
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:366:47
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:106:26
__guard
    MessageQueue.js:314:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:105:17
```

---

What can I do about this?
I've tried pretty much everything, and i've downloaded the fonts needed as well. Thanks.

Comment: The warning states that you must load the font via `Font.loadAsync`. Here's a tutorial on Expo https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/

Comment: I've tried literally everything I could find on this error. I also tried updating EXPO, deleting node_modules and using npm install to see if my problem would go away. But doing all of those made my error even worse. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 0):

in your `App.js` you can use something like this:

```
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAssets();
  }

  async loadAssets() {
    const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
      { ionicons: require('../assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf') }, //for custom fonts
      Feather.font, // for the @expo/vector-icons
    ]);

    await Promise.all([...fontAssets]);

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootNavigation {...this.props} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your project is structured similar to Kitten Tricks application, take a look at the [application root](https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks/blob/next/src/app.component.tsx#L35). This includes a font map, that is passed into `Font.loadAsync()`, like it is described in [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/#loading-the-font-in-your-app)